# Why does my JQuery Image swap not work in firefox or chrome, but fine in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Relatively new to JQuery. I've got some code that does a banner swap with a fade in fade out transition. The images swap as expected in IE8, chrome, and firefox. However, the actual fade, the smooth transition between images only works in IE.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a fix?

Javascript:

```
function swapImages() {
            var $active = $('#transitionImagePlaceHolder .active');
            var $next = ($('#transitionImagePlaceHolder .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#transitionImagePlaceHolder .active').next() : $('#transitionImagePlaceHolder img:first');

            $active.fadeOut( 'slow', function () {

                $next.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active');
                $active.removeClass('active');
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);
        });
```

CSS:

```
#transitionImagePlaceHolder
    {

    }


    #transitionImagePlaceHolder
    {
        position:relative;
        left: 26px;
    }

    #transitionImagePlaceHolder img
    {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:4;
        left:10;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="transitionImagePlaceHolder">

      <img class="active" src="Images/TransitionImages/Trans_Img_1.jpg" />
      <img src="Images/TransitionImages/Trans_Img_2.jpg" />
      <img src="Images/TransitionImages/Trans_Img_3.jpg" />


</div>
```

Comment: Using your code, the transitions are the same in all three browsers here (smooth).

Comment: This is smooth for me too, testing in Chrome. Put the example here: http://jsbin.com/ekazi3/edit  (sped it up and used boxes instead of images). Are you looking for a cross-fade instead of a fade-in / fade-out transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is because I put together the example below at JSFiddle and it works fine in both Safari and Firefox.  The only thing I can think is that you are defining your swapImages function somewhere you shouldn't be. You should probably install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox and see if you get an error.

http://jsfiddle.net/GtV3U/

Edit: My suspicion is that you need to take the setInterval call out of $(document).ready(function () {
}).

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Firstly this looks like a really useful tool I hadn't heard of, and also it highlighted what the problem was - I was using version 1.4.1, as comes with the new Visual Studio 2010. Swapping it out for 1.4.2 has solved the issue. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery, use the small and efficient [JsSlideshow](http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/JsSlideshow)
See a quick demo [here](http://kinsey.no/projects/jsslideshow/) - it works on all browsers.

It can easily be set up like this

```
var sl = new JsSlideshow({
    target: "slideshow",
    images: ["4504470765_90aa261be6.jpg", "images/4510204607_42bbb55d9c.jpg", "images/4510826808_f6edfc906a.jpg", "images/4513712885_0c008e3638.jpg"],
    transition: 3000,
    time: 2000,
    url: "http://www.flickr.com/photos/bobowen"
});
```

Comment: I want to stay in JQuery if possible. It's a framework I want to learn so gonna stick with it. Is there another method in the framework that is more likely to work cross browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's because Firefox and Chrome (probably correctly) don't modify `display` css property while fadeIn/fadeOut.

Do a quick test: instead of `display:none;`in css, do really quick `fadeOut` (20 ms) on non-active images after (document).ready.

If it'll work, you'll know you have to find another way of hiding images on load.